# Searching doesn't change backgroundcolor

Tags: reactjs, search, react-native

I am trying to make a background color to change on my flatist whenever I press the search bar to make an input. When testing by making `searchBarFocused:true` an error pops up saying `Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state')`.

Here is the full code of the SearchScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, TextInput, Text, View, FlatList, Keyboard, Image, TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';

const listItems = ['Meo Sudoeste', 'Vodafone Paredes de Coura', 'Super Bock Super Rock', 'NOS Primavera Sound', 'Rock in Rio', 'EDP Cool Jazz']

function SearchScreen({navigation}) {

  state={
searchBarFocused: true
  }


  return (
<View style={styles.screen}>
  <Animatable.View animation='slideInLeft' duration={500} style={styles.container}>
    <Icon name='ios-search' style={styles.icon}/>
    <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
              underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' 
              placeholder="Procura aqui"
              placeholderTextColor = "black"
              selectionColor="black"
              keyboardType="default"/>
  </Animatable.View>
  <View style={styles.teste}> 
    <Text style={styles.festivais}>Recomendados</Text>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.festivais_lista}>

      //I took this part off because it is irrelevant

    </ScrollView>
    <FlatList
      style={{backgroundColor:this.state.searchBarFocused?'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)':'white'}}
      data = {listItems}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Text style = {{ padding:20, fontSize:20}}>{item}</Text>}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />
  </View>
</View>
  );
}

SearchScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Procurar',
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

//Took this part off, its irrelevant

export default SearchScreen;
```

Why am I getting this error and can I correct it? Please help me

Comment: `this` is not defined in a functional component, you probably just want to reference `state.searchBarFocused`.

Comment: Well then how do I reference that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using functional component in your codebase, so you should use React Hooks to handle states.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react' 

function SearchScreen({navigation}) {

 const [searchBarFocused, setSearchBarFocused] = useState(false)


  return (
<View style={styles.screen}>
  <Animatable.View animation='slideInLeft' duration={500} style={styles.container}>
    <Icon name='ios-search' style={styles.icon}/>
    <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
              underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' 
              placeholder="Procura aqui"
              placeholderTextColor = "black"
              selectionColor="black"
              keyboardType="default"/>
  </Animatable.View>
  <View style={styles.teste}> 
    <Text style={styles.festivais}>Recomendados</Text>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.festivais_lista}>

      //I took this part off because it is irrelevant

    </ScrollView>
    <FlatList
      style={{backgroundColor:searchBarFocused?'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)':'white'}}
      data = {listItems}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Text style = {{ padding:20, fontSize:20}}>{item}</Text>}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />
  </View>
</View>
  );
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to use Class components, then you can use class members as states.

```
class SearchScreen extends React.Component {

  state={
searchBarFocused: true
  }


  return (
<View style={styles.screen}>
  <Animatable.View animation='slideInLeft' duration={500} style={styles.container}>
    <Icon name='ios-search' style={styles.icon}/>
    <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
              underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' 
              placeholder="Procura aqui"
              placeholderTextColor = "black"
              selectionColor="black"
              keyboardType="default"/>
  </Animatable.View>
  <View style={styles.teste}> 
    <Text style={styles.festivais}>Recomendados</Text>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.festivais_lista}>

      //I took this part off because it is irrelevant

    </ScrollView>
    <FlatList
      style={{backgroundColor:this.state.searchBarFocused?'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)':'white'}}
      data = {listItems}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Text style = {{ padding:20, fontSize:20}}>{item}</Text>}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />
  </View>
</View>
  );
}
```

Comment: It worked! But where would I use setSearchBarFocused on the whole function?

Comment: @Tiago2.0 `setSearchBarFocused` is like `setState` and it's used for updating states in React Hook API. In your case I think it should be used for example on `onPress` of a button or anything else. like: `<Button onPress={() => setSearchBarFocused(prevState => !prevState)} />`

Answer (score 0):

to use this.state you should have a class based component or use Hook instead for your functional component

Comment: I need the function to navigate screens. How do I use Hooks in this particular situation?